# Xna StencilBuffers

Tags: c#, xna

I have been working tirelessly trying to get stencil buffers to work with no luck in xna 4.0

```
 private void DrawReflectionMask()
    {
        if (AlphaEffect == null)
        {
            AlphaEffect = new AlphaTestEffect(GraphicsDevice);
            AlphaEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
            AlphaEffect.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
            AlphaEffect.AlphaFunction = CompareFunction.Equal;
            AlphaEffect.ReferenceAlpha = 0;
            AlphaEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            AlphaEffect.View = Matrix.Identity;

        }
        if(mReflection == null)
        {
            mReflection = Content.Load<Texture2D>("reflection");
            mMask = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ice-mask");
        }
        mSpriteBatch.End();

        RenderTarget2D lMaskRenderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(mGraphicsDevice, mPixelViewport.Width, mPixelViewport.Height,false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8, 0 ,RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents);


        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(lMaskRenderTarget);
        BlendState lOldState = GraphicsDevice.BlendState;
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = ABlendState;
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Stencil | ClearOptions.Target, new Color(0,0,0,1), 0, 0);
        SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,null,null, AlwaysStencilState,null);
        for (int x = mViewPort.Viewport.Left; x < mViewPort.Viewport.Right; x++)
        {
            for (int y = mViewPort.Viewport.Top; y < mViewPort.Viewport.Bottom; y++)
            {
                int lTileIndex = mMap[x, y].TileID;
                Rectangle lSourceRectangle = new Rectangle((lTileIndex % 8) * 32, (lTileIndex / 8) * 32, 32, 32);
                mSpriteBatch.Draw(mMask,
                                  new Vector2((x - mViewPort.Viewport.X) * 32, (y - mViewPort.Viewport.Y) * 32),
                                  lSourceRectangle,
                                  Color.White);
            }
        }
        SpriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = lOldState;
        SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, EqualStencilState, null);
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                SpriteBatch.Draw(mReflection, new Vector2(x * 256, y * 256), Color.White);
            }
        }
        SpriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        //lMaskRenderTarget.SaveAsPng(new FileStream("Image.png", FileMode.Create), lMaskRenderTarget.Width, lMaskRenderTarget.Height);
        SpriteBatch.Begin();
        SpriteBatch.Draw(lMaskRenderTarget, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    }
```

This is my function that i'm using to try to draw to the stencil mask...

```
public static DepthStencilState AlwaysStencilState = new DepthStencilState()
    {

        StencilEnable = true,
        StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Always,
        StencilPass = StencilOperation.Replace,
        ReferenceStencil = 1,
        DepthBufferEnable = false,
    };
    public static DepthStencilState EqualStencilState = new DepthStencilState()
    {
        StencilEnable = true,
        StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Equal,
        StencilPass = StencilOperation.Keep,
        ReferenceStencil = 1,
        DepthBufferEnable = false,
    };
```

These are my stencil states...

What i'm trying to do is cover up parts of a texture based on the mask..

Here is my reflection...

http://www.badsheepgaming.com/Kevin/reflection.png

Here is my mask

http://www.badsheepgaming.com/Kevin/ice-mask.png

Here is what im getting with this code

http://www.badsheepgaming.com/Kevin/outcome.png

and here is what i'm expecting

http://www.badsheepgaming.com/Kevin/cow.png

Answer (score 0):

It's late, and I'm not very good at explaining stencil buffers, but I've found my way around with them before. Also, I have no idea if this is going to work, but no-one else seems to be responding, so I thought I'd give it a shot.

Without actually compiling your code, it look like everything is setup to work as you intend. Draw tiles, and then draw reflection only on top of tiles, correct? I believe the problem here is that even when your tile is completely transparent, those pixels are still being drawn, and therefore the stencil test is passing, and replacing the existing 0 with a 1.

**Step 1**: Testing to see if that's actually the problem.

Try to draw every other tile... `if((x + y) % 2 == 0) { /* draw tile */ }`. If this makes a checker-board pattern for your reflection, then you know the transparent pixels are passing your stencil test. Proceed to step two (otherwise let me know it didn't work).

**Step 2**: Fixing the stencil pass problem

You'll need a way to clip those transparent pixels before they have a chance to pass the stencil test. You can either do this by using a Color Key, or a pixel shader. To use the Color Key, select your image resource for the tiles, and click on the properties tab/menu. Under this you should find the "Use Color Key" and "Color Key" options. You should be able to select the transparent color of your image as the Color Key, and this will prevent that portion of the image from rendering (it'll be clipped), and won't pass the stencil test.

**Alternative #1**:

You can program a pixel shader that draws the reflection while drawing your tiles. By doing this, it will allow you to add the correct amount of reflection to each part of the tile, even if the tile has "feathered" (gradient transparency) edges. You won't be able to get a smooth look like this with the Color Key.

**Alternative #2**:

Assuming you draw the tiles on a completely transparent background, you can draw the Reflection with a special blend mode.

```
Source = DestAlpha
Dest = One
```

This will additively draw the reflection onto the opaque portions of the image. Or, you could multiple them on to each other (I think this is how it's setup?):

```
Source = Dest
Dest = Zero
```

Anyways, I hope this helps in some way, or at least leads you in the right direction. I wish you better luck in finding a good response. :)